# Signal where the bilateral z-transform exists, but the unilteral z-transform doesn't for some value?

Tags: signal-processing, z-transform

Like the title says, I'm looking for a signal such that the bilateral Z-transform exists, but the unilateral transform does not exist for some arbitrary value or set of values for z. So, in more formal terms, there exists some $z_0\in \mathbb{C}$ such that the following sum converges

$$\sum_{n= -\infty}^{\infty}x[n]z_0^{-n}$$

but this sum does not

$$\sum_{n= 0}^{\infty}x[n]z_0^{-n}$$

Another way to put this question is if it is possible for the unilateral z-transform of a signal to have poles in the region of the complex plane where the bilateral z-transform for the same signal converges.

Comment: How are you defining the doubly-infinite series ($\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x[n]z_0^{-n}$)? Is it defined as $\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\sum\limits_{n=-N}^{N}x[n]z_0^{-n}$? If so, you can construct an example by making it so that $x[n]z_0^{-n}$ is an odd function of $n$ (so each negative $n$ term just cancels with the corresponding positive $n$ term), while $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}x[n]z_0^{-n}$ is divergent. An example would be to take $z_0=1$ and define $x[n]=\begin{cases}1&\text{if } n\ge 0 \\ -1&\text{if }n<0\end{cases}$.